# Trigger jQuery click event by url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery click function on my page which triggers the loading of multiple html page inside a div. I want to specify a url that will trigger this event, such as test.com#about

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#about").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('about.html');
               }); 
               $("#comunity").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('comunity.html');
               });
               $("#sponsor").click(function(){
                $('#result').load('sponsor.html');
               }); 
             });
        </script>

    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="comunity" href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a id="sponsor" href="#">Sponsor</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="result" style="clear:both;">loading...
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at - https://github.com/flatiron/director

Comment: @Braj sorry for this noob question. I want to to specify the url like test.com#about so it will load about page in div by default without needing too be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the hash value from url and load the page. Read more about [Location hash Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash) {
        $('#result').load(hash.slice(1)+'.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: might want to add an error handler to that, or validate hash values

Comment: hash value contains `#`. Just skip first character of hash value.

Comment: right but point is it assumes the matching file exists. `#aboutt` would fail

Comment: @charlietfl I agree we can add exception handling for such cases.